# Como garantir que um Servlet seja Implantado no Tomcat 7 usando Servlet Container 3.0?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlet

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que usa a API Servlet 3.0 via Anotações e portando não precisa de arquivo WEB-INF/web.xml

O problema que as vezes quando faço o Deploy no Tomcat 7 o Servlet não fica disponível e passo a receber erro 404. Não aparece nenhuma mensagem de erro no LOG.

Em resumo, gostaria de forçar o Tomcat a enxergar o o meu Servlet, de preferência programaticamente para não precisar de editar descritores JEE em XML.

OBS: O Servlet estava disponível e aparentemente sem modificação passou a acusar erro 404 quando fiz um novo Deploy da Aplicação.

Estou declarando o Servlet com a Anotação `@WebServlet` onde uso somente os atributos `name` e `urlPatterns`

Esta é a abordagem correta ? Falta alguma anotação ? Preciso usar a Interface `javax.servlet.ServletRegistration` ?

Comment: Qual versão do Tomcat você esta utilizando? Tentou utilizar a versão 8?

Comment: Estou usando a versão `7.0.52` mas já testei na `7.0.47` também. Segundo a Documentação [neste Link](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) a API Servlet 3.0 é suportada desde a versão `7.0`

Answer (score 2):

Se você usar o **Tomcat Embedded** poderá forçar o Tomcat a enxergar o seu Servlet programaticamente e não precisar editar descritores JEE em XML.

Segue um exemplo abaixo onde não é necessário usar a anotação `@WebServlet` :

**Método main**

```
// Para tratar o CTRL-C
final Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            tomcat.stop();
        } catch (LifecycleException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});

// inicio
tomcat.setPort(Integer.valueOf(args[0]));
Log containerLogger = context.getLogger();

try {
    Context context = tomcat.addWebapp("/",
            new File(".").getAbsolutePath());

    containerLogger.info("*** INICIANDO ***");

    containerLogger.info("*** iniciando o Tomcat com o servlet "
            + MyDynServlet.class.getSimpleName());

    tomcat.start();

    String myDynServletName = MyDynServlet.class.getSimpleName()
            .toLowerCase();
    Wrapper myDynServlet = context.createWrapper();
    myDynServlet.setName(myDynServletName);
    myDynServlet.setServletClass(MyDynServlet.class.getCanonicalName());
    myDynServlet.addInitParameter("debug", "0");
    myDynServlet.addInitParameter("listings", "false");
    myDynServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    context.addChild(myDynServlet);
    // O mapping do Servlet pode vir de qualquer fonte. 
    // Abaixo está hard-coded
    context.addServletMapping("/mydynservlet", myDynServletName);
    // Para ajudar na resolução de problemas listo os mappings
    String[] servletMappings = context.findServletMappings();
    for (String mapping : servletMappings) {
        containerLogger.info("*** ServletMapping " + mapping);
    }
} catch (ServletException | LifecycleException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

int CINCO_SEGUNDOS = 5 * 1000;
final Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Wait until a proper shutdown command is received, then
        // cancel timer thread.
        containerLogger.info("***  AWAIT Server");

        tomcat.getServer().await();

        containerLogger.info("***  Server Shutdown Complete ***");
        containerLogger.info("***  Cancelando Timer Thread  ***");
        timer.cancel();
    }
}, CINCO_SEGUNDOS);

// Você pode desejar fazer algo depois de carregar o Tomcat em outra Thread.
```

Observe que foi criado uma Timer Task apenas para não bloquear a Thread corrente. Isto é opcional.

**Dependências Maven:**

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <tomcat-embed.version>7.0.52</tomcat-embed.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat-embed.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-api</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat-embed.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat-embed.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat-embed.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-websocket</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat-embed.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

A dependência com Websocket é opcional.